# Is it possible to produce an ordered batch of events with an attribute stating the event (ordered) position?

Tags: postgresql, esper

Using **Esper** engine to write continuous queries, is it possible to produce an **ordered** batch of events with an (extra) "column"/attribute witch  states the event ordered position?

Imagine the following Esper's query:

```
SELECT  id, val                                                                         
FROM Datastream.win:length(10)
OUTPUT SNAPSHOT EVERY 1 EVENTS                                                          
ORDER BY val DESC
```

For instance, such query would produce the following type of output:

```
id | val  
 D | 17  
 B | 12  
 C | 11  
 A | 8
```

I'm asking if there is any esper's operator capable to produce the extra "column" **rank** for the previous batch of (new) events:

```
id | val | rank 
 D | 17  | 1
 B | 12  | 2
 C | 11  | 3
 A | 8   | 4
```

For those who are familiar with pgSQL window functions, I'm looking for the [rank()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) equivalent operator for Esper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that currently exists. Esper project's JIRA is at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ESPER and JIRA accounts can be created at http://xircles.codehaus.org/